# What is the opposite of "spread something (out): to move your arms, legs, fingers, etc. far apart from each other"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> [spread](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spread_1?q=spread): ​[transitive] spread something (out) **to move your arms, legs,
>   fingers, etc. far apart from each other**
>
> She spread her arms and the child ran towards her.

---

Ok, my toddler often spreads his legs so far out like this when sitting, which is not nice.

[image]

I want to find a word that express the opposite. That word means "**to move your arms, legs, fingers, etc. close to each other**".

"**fold up**"? or "**close**"?

Can I say:

**Please don't spread your legs so far out like that, fold them up?**

Comment: While this is quite old, I just realize perhaps a better way to say this could be "keep your knees apart"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Legs:**

"Keep your legs closer (or close together)."

> Keep your legs close together with your feet lightly touching each
>   other. *([Yoga Poses: Speedy Study Guides](https://books.google.com/books?id=y5-qBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT1&lpg=PT1&dq=%22keep%20your%20legs%20close%22&source=bl&ots=Xw7lkpQU6x&sig=ACfU3U2stkD7RV5EzWQzXq8C9bIOzTQdaA&hl=sl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjy4IOw67znAhVFy6QKHVJSCcgQ6AEwEXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22keep%20your%20legs%20close%22&f=false))*

or

> Don't keep your legs apart (like that). *([Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/your+legs+apart))*

Note:

a) "Far apart" is mainly used in the exercise context as an instruction what *to do:* "Sit with legs far apart." and not to say what *not to do:* "Don't sit with legs far apart."

b) Saying: "Keep your legs together" or "close*d.*" or "Don't spread your legs." or "Don't sit with your legs open." can have a strong sexual meaning.

**Arms:**

For arms, it's better if you say: "Don't spread your arms." because "Keep your arms together." actually means "*hands* together."

> Don't spread your arms so wide. *([Celticlyricscorner.net](http://www.celticlyricscorner.net/polwart/daisy.htm))*

**Fingers:**

> Don't spread your fingers unnaturally to reach keys lying further out,
>   but simply move your arm. *([Rsipain.com](https://www.rsipain.com/work-habits.php))*

Note: "Fold up" the legs, arms or fingers means bending them rather than keeping them together.

Comment: I would add I would avoid saying something like `Keep your legs closed` as it could be interrupted to have an underlining comment it.

Comment: @Matthew, I'm aware of this issue, so which version you think is least problematic? I guess, closer?

Comment: @jen I'm honestly unsure, I think it's a good question because I don't have a good answer to the question myself, I think close together as you stated is good but was more for non-native English speakers to keep in mind about `Keep your legs closed`

Comment: what about "sit / stand with your legs wide apart"? does it sound sexually? https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/wide_2

Comment: @Tom, "Wide apart" is much better than "wide open" in this regard.